# How find and replace all occurrences of substring in string in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I looked at the existing topics, but my task is slightly different from those on the forum.
I have the value:

```
int j = 37;
```

And I have one of the strings:

```java
1) String s1 = "5+2+5+2 --j *2*7+3";
2) String s1 = "5+2+5+2 j-- *2*7+3";
3) String s1 = "5+2+5+2 ++j *2*7+3";
4) String s1 = "5+2+5+2 j++ *2*7+3";
```

I need with regular expression find `--j`, `j--`, `++j`, `j++` and replace this occurrences of substring in string with number value `j`;

Result string must be like this:

```
1) 5+2+5+2 36 *2*7+3
2) 5+2+5+2 36 *2*7+3
3) 5+2+5+2 38 *2*7+3
4) 5+2+5+2 38 *2*7+3
```

With pattern `str.split(search).join(replacement)` I can replace the char `j` with number `37`:

```
str.split("j").join(37);
```

Then I get:

```java
1) String s1 = "5+2+5+2 --37 *2*7+3";
2) String s1 = "5+2+5+2 37-- *2*7+3";
3) String s1 = "5+2+5+2 ++37 *2*7+3";
4) String s1 = "5+2+5+2 37++ *2*7+3";
```

**Question:**
But how to perform the arithmetic operation (`increment`, `decrement`) at this time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in the question, the operations do not follow the Java behaviour, i.e. pre- and postincrement both behave like preincrement.

To implement this behaviour, we need two regular expressions:

- One expression matching all `--j` and `j--` to replace them with the value of `j - 1`:

  `[-]{2}j|j[-]{2}` [<kbd>Regex101 demo</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/6pZR94/2)
- One expression matching all `++j` and `j++` to replace them with the value of `j + 1`:

  `[+]{2}j|j[+]{2}` [<kbd>Regex101 demo</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/j0NSDo/2)

Putting it together, we can write the following method:

```
public static String replaceJWith(String s, int valueForJ) {
    s = s.replaceAll("[-]{2}j|j[-]{2}", Integer.toString(valueForJ - 1));
    return s.replaceAll("[+]{2}j|j[+]{2}", Integer.toString(valueForJ + 1));
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/xWWf8C)

This implementation assumes that each occurrence of `j` is pre- or suffixed by `++` or `--`. Also, since we never really change the value of `j`, using multiple pre-, and postincrement operators in a single `String` will result in unexpected behaviour.

---

If we want to mimic the Java behaviour (i.e. distinguish between pre- and postincrement), we need three different regular expressions since we have to replace `j` with three different values:

- One regex to replace `j(++|--)` with the original value for `j`:

  `j(?:[+]{2}|[-]{2})` [<kbd>Regex101 demo</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/nNB50X/3)
- One regex to replace `++j` with the value `j + 1`:

  `[+]{2}j` [<kbd>Regex101 demo</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/ZYJTtq/2)
- One regex to replace `--j` with the value `j - 1`:

  `[-]{2}j` [<kbd>Regex101 demo</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/vJgJmR/2)

Setting it all together, we can write the following Java method:

```
public static String replaceJWith(String s, int valueForJ) {
    s = s.replaceAll("j(?:[+]{2}|[-]{2})", Integer.toString(valueForJ));
    s = s.replaceAll("[+]{2}j", Integer.toString(valueForJ + 1));
    return s.replaceAll("[-]{2}j", Integer.toString(valueForJ - 1));
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/mX4z6l)

This solution has the same limitations as the first solution.

Answer (score 5):

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int j = 37;
        String s1 = "5+2+5+2 ++j *2*7+3";
        
        // this line swap "j--" or "--j" on j--
        s1 = s1.replaceAll("j--|--j", j-1 + "");
        
        // this line swaps "j++" or "++j" on j++
        s1 = s1.replaceAll("(j\\+\\+)|(\\+\\+j)", j+1 + "");
        
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `j(--|++)` will return `37`

Comment: @Turing85 I don't understand what you mean

Comment: I understand my mistake

Comment: Code-only answer are discouraged. Instead, we should describe the problem and how to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

`String.replaceAll` may be used as follows:

```java
int j = 37;
String[] d = {
    "5+2+5+2 --j *2*7+3",
    "5+2+5+2 j-- *2*7+3",
    "5+2+5+2 ++j *2*7+3",
    "5+2+5+2 j++ *2*7+3"
};
        
Arrays.stream(d)
      .map(s -> s.replaceAll("--j|j--", Integer.valueOf(j - 1).toString()))
      .map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\+\\+j|j\\+\\+", Integer.valueOf(j + 1).toString()))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

to provide expected output:

```
5+2+5+2 36 *2*7+3
5+2+5+2 36 *2*7+3
5+2+5+2 38 *2*7+3
5+2+5+2 38 *2*7+3
```

Comment: Code-only answer are discouraged. Instead, we should describe the problem and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a series of `if` statements that check the string for the presence of each of those patterns using `contains()` and then replace the pattern with the corresponding value:

```
if (s1.contains("--j") {
  s1.replace("--j", String.valueOf(j-1)); //assuming you have declared int j = 37; before 
} else if (s1.contains("j--")) { 
  //etc.
} [...]
```